# Jasperserver report dynamic select query according to scheduled report reciepents

Tags: email, oracle11g, jasperserver

I have some data as the table below. I want to send report to owner of  each data by email which displayed  at the "Email" column . So , is  there any way to prepare report for each  User and then, run a scheduled job for that report and send email to that User. ( I am using Jasperserver 6.0.3 and OracleDB for select query)

(I dont want to create a scheduled job for each user. I create only one scheduled job which works for all users.)

Thanks in advance...

MY RAW DATA:

```
 Data Usage(MB)           User                Email                 Date
 550                      Alice          alice@alice.com          16.01.2017
 860                      Bob            bob@bob.com              16.01.2017
1450                      Charlie        charlie@charlie.com      16.01.2017
 230                      Dave           dave@dave.com            16.01.2017
 475                      Evelyn         evelyn@evelyn.com        16.01.2017
 900                      Alice          alice@alice.com          17.01.2017
 160                      Bob            bob@bob.com              17.01.2017
 340                      Charlie        charlie@charlie.com      17.01.2017
2560                      Dave           dave@dave.com            17.01.2017
1175                      Evelyn         evelyn@evelyn.com        17.01.2017
```

INTENDED RESULT FOR ALICE:

```
Data Usage(MB)  User            Email                 Date
550             Alice         alice@alice.com       16.01.2017
900             Alice         alice@alice.com       17.01.2017
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this issue by creating a new job for every user.

1. My report url is as shown below.

`http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2FTEST&reportUnit=%2Freports%2FTEST%2FMy_Report&standAlone=true&userName=Alice`

2. I create a parameter as "userName" in my jasperreport.
3. My jasperreport select query is like this :

`Select * from myTable where myTable.User = $P!{userName}`

4. Create new job for each User. Ex:While scheduled job creation at Parameters tab, enter "Alice" to userName parameter input; then at Notification tab enter "alice@alice.com" to reciepent email.